# how to print specific class logs which mentioned in log4j properties file using spring AOP

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, aspectj, spring-aop

I am new to spring and log4j
I try to implement logging using aop and log4j.
 my logger class as below

```
  @Aspect
    public class AspectLogger {
        private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());


        @Before("execution(* controller.*.*(..)))")
        public void logBeforeV1(JoinPoint joinPoint) 
        {
            log.debug("entering " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        }
    }
```

In my controller package there are more than 20 classes and when mentioned @Before("execution(* controller.*.*(..)))")
entering log for all classes method are printed.

So how to print log only those classes which configured in log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the logger in the normal way:

```
@Before("execution(* controller.*.*(..)))")
public void logBeforeV1(JoinPoint joinPoint) 
{
  Logger log = Logger.getLogger(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType());
  log.debug("entering " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

Comment: I do not see what an around advice would change in comparison with a before advice. It does not solve the OP's problem. What does, though, is to create a logger for the target class as shown in your example. So your code is correct, but I guess the "You will need to use an Around advice or else you code will run into a brick wall!" part is not. Good code, bad explanation.